# Set Vim window size and selection from command line

Tags: vim, split, window

I want to launch two files from the command line and I want the window to be split horizontally. This can be achieved with the following command:

```
vim -o index.html index.1
```

Which gives me the following output split evenly

[image]

What I want, instead, is for the top window to be substantially larger, like so

[image]

How do I achieve this? Also, currently, the top window is selected, which is what I want. However, if it wasn't selected, or I wanted the bottom window selected, how would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the two files with

```
vim index.html +10sp index.1
```

After `vim` has read `index.html` it executes the ex command `10sp`. That means that the current window is split into two with the new window being 10 rows high. After that `index.1` is read by vim and loaded into the currently active window.

If you already set `splitbelow` in your `.vimrc` `index.1` is loaded into the bottom window that is active at the same time.

For example if you want the top window to be active and `splitbelow` is set you can append the corresponding ex command to the line

```
vim index.html +10sp index.1 +"wincmd k"
```

Comment: you don't need to '-o' flag?

Comment: `vim` allows command line options and filenames to be mixed. Since I horizontally split the initial window by "hand" i don't need the `-o` flag in my case.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to make the top window 80% of the available size:

`vim +'execute "resize" (&lines / 10) * 8' -o file1 file2`

See `:help :resize` and `:help 'lines'` for more information.

Small clarification: `&` is used in front of options to retrieve its value. Thus `&lines` holds the value of what you could set yourself, e.g.`:set lines=100`. In this case, `&lines` gets set by Vim on-the-fly even when you resize the window that holds Vim.